# Need advice in data model

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

Need advice on data model for my use case.
I have two parameters to store, A for things of type T and,B for things of type U(which is set of T's)
Lets say every object of type T has 2 properties p1 and p2, now 
A= (count of t's with p1)/(count of t's with p1)+(count of t's with p1)

B=  (A1+A2+.. )for its set of T's/ (Number of T's in U).

Now, i have to tackle the storage and updation of both A and B whenever a new object of type T is added/modified.(Almost instantly)

I have decided to tackle the calculation of A as follows, to maintain a table like  (T id, No. of p1,  No. of p2), thereby every time the number changes i just update 2nd or 3rd column and i can calculate A on the fly. 
But i am confused on how to optimize calculation of B??
My initial thoughts were to write a trigger on above table so that whenever something gets updated, recalculate B for that U object, but i think that would give me very poor performance when i scale up,
Any suggestions what else i might do here?

Example:
Say U is a city with many blocks(T).
Now, every block will have say p1 number of non veg restaurants and p2 number of veg. 
So, A for every block would be p1/(p1+p2)
and B for every city would be A1+A2+.. / count(blocks) in that city.
How do i store the initially calculated A and B for all the objects such that when p1 and p2 keep changing, i need update A and B almost instantly.

Adding metrics, to have more clarity on the desired solution,

1. I already have 100k blocks and close to 1000 cities. And this number
   is going to rise in future.    My requirement is, once i calculate A
   and B for all the existing data, any updation to p1 and p2 that
   causes change say 'deltaA'.Now this 'deltaA' should be easily appended to   'A' rather than recalculating A(similarly for B), can't we have some data model that    can support this?
2. Latency
   should be ~100ms i,e A and B should be available after p1/p2 change.
3. Frequency of writes will be in spikes, it will be a    100 or 1000
   writes simultaneously or 3-5.

Comment: You may want to include what latency you can tolerate on B because an async process of throwing an event and letting a listener handle that update could work.  Also, this is not a typical pattern to store in a relational DB, so if you're limited to mysql you may want to check out its JSON column capabilities.

Comment: I need the values of A and B almost instantly after any change to an object of type T happens, thats why spending more time on the db design so that it can scale. I am actually not limited to mysql, how would a Nosql db help in this case?

Comment: Give us a short set of sample data, plus the computations and desired result.

Comment: added an example scenario.

Comment: You didn't show any reason not to use a clean relational data model. Did you run any performance tests?

Comment: I want that clean relational model. Can you help me with that?

Comment: We need a lot more information : first, show us the simplest way to store your data (I can't really picture it out), the show us the pseudo code that should work on this table. Next, how many read ? how many write ? how many lines in the DB ? What are your requirements ?

Answer (score 8):

Using your cities/blocks example, your schema could be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    `city_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `zip` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE blocks (
    `block_id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `city_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `p1` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `p2` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`block_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`city_id`)
);
```

Your query for a given city (`city_id = 123`) would be:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT AVG(p1/(p1+p2)) AS B
FROM blocks b
WHERE b.city_id = 123
```

Note: `AVG(x) = SUM(x) / COUNT(x)`

Now, if you worry about performance you should define some expected numbers:

- Number of cities
- (Average) Number of blocks per city
- Hardware you will/can use
- Queries you will usually run
- Number of queries per hour/minute/sec

If you have defined these numbers, you can generate some dummy/fake data to run performance tests against it.

Here is an example with 1000 cities and 100K blocks (100 blocks per city on average):

First create a helper table with 100K sequence numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS seq100k
    SELECT NULL AS seq
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c1
    JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS c2
    JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS c3
    LIMIT 100000;
ALTER TABLE seq100k CHANGE COLUMN seq seq MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

With MariaDB you can use the sequence plugin instead.

Generate the data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS blocks;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities;
CREATE TABLE cities (
    `city_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `zip` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
)
    SELECT seq AS city_id
         , floor(rand(1)*10+1) as country_id
         , floor(rand(2)*99999+1) as zip
         , rand(3) as name
    FROM seq100k
    LIMIT 1000;

CREATE TABLE blocks (
    `block_id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `city_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `p1` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `p2` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`block_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`city_id`)
)
    SELECT seq AS block_id
         , floor(rand(4)*1000+1) as city_id
         , floor(rand(5)*11) as p1
         , floor(rand(6)*20+1) as p2
    FROM seq100k
    LIMIT 100000;
```

Now you can run your queries. Note that I will not use exact runtimes. If you need them to be exact, you should use profiling.

Running **Query 1** my GUI (HeidiSQL) shows `0.000 sec`, which I call "almost instant".

You might want to run a query like:

**Query 2**

```
SELECT b.city_id, AVG(p1/(p1+p2)) AS B
FROM blocks b
GROUP BY b.city_id
ORDER BY B DESC
LIMIT 10
```

HeidiSQL shows `0.078 sec`.

Using a covering index

```
ALTER TABLE `blocks`
    DROP INDEX `city_id`,
    ADD INDEX `city_id` (`city_id`, `p1`, `p2`);
```

you can decrease the runtime to `0.031 sec`. If that isn't fast enough, you should think about some caching strategies. One way (beside caching on application level) is to use triggers to manage a new column in the `cities` table (let's just call it `B`):

```
ALTER TABLE `cities` ADD COLUMN `B` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `name`;
```

Define the update trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `blocks_after_update`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `blocks_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `blocks` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if new.p1 <> old.p1 or new.p2 <> old.p2 then
        update cities c
        set c.B = (
            select avg(p1/(p1+p2))
            from blocks b
            where b.city_id = new.city_id
        )
        where c.city_id = new.city_id;
    end if;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Update test:

**Query 3**

```
UPDATE blocks b SET p2 = p2 + 100 WHERE 1=1;
UPDATE blocks b SET p2 = p2 - 100 WHERE 1=1;
```

This query runs in `2.500 sec` without the trigger and `60 sec` with the trigger. This might look like a lot of overhead - But consider, that we are updating 100K rows twice - which means an average of `60K msec / 200K updates = 0.3 msec/update`.

And now you can get the same result from **Query 2** with

**Query 4**

```
SELECT c.city_id, c.B
FROM cities c
ORDER BY c.B DESC
LIMIT 10
```

"almost instantly" (`0.000 sec`).

You can still optimize the trigger if you need. Using an additional column `block_count` in the `cities` table (which also needs to be managed with triggers).

Add column:

```
ALTER TABLE `cities`
    ADD COLUMN `block_count` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `B`;
```

Init data:

```
UPDATE cities c SET c.block_count = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM blocks b
    WHERE b.city_id = c.city_id
)
WHERE 1=1;
```

Rewrite the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `blocks_after_update`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `blocks_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `blocks` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    declare old_A, new_A double;
    if new.p1 <> old.p1 or new.p2 <> old.p2 then
        set old_A = old.p1/(old.p1+old.p2);
        set new_A = new.p1/(new.p1+new.p2);
        update cities c
            set c.B = (c.B * c.block_count - old_A + new_A) / c.block_count
            where c.city_id = new.city_id;
    end if;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

With this trigger **Query 3** now runs in `8.5 sec`. This means an overhead of `0.03 msec` per update.

Note that you will also need to define the INSERT and DELETE triggers. And you will need to add more logic (e.g. to handle changes in `city_id` on updates). But it's also possible that you will not need any trigger at all.

Comment: nice job, exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Wow, that's really good analysis, I haven't done performance testing but suggested a similar relational model. But my boss says, business logic should be out of db, db should only be used as a data store, which in a way makes sense to me, how do you counter that?

Comment: @Bhargav "db should only be used as a data store" - At extreme, that would mean, that you write your own RDBMS as part of business logic for every application you develop.

Comment: haha thats another interpretation. Your answer  is excellent but unfortunately i cannot mark it correct yet, as this is not what i need, i have updated the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a meterialized view (concept of postgres), in mysql it doesn't exist, but you can use a table for that:

```
CREATE TABLE analyzeVeg 
SELECT b.city_id, AVG(p1/(p1+p2)) AS B
FROM blocks b
GROUP BY b.city_id;
```

Took me with 1000 cities and 100'000 blocks 200ms to create and almost for the query

```
select * from analyzeVeg
```

around 1 ms.

You can either actualise the data in a trigger, or in the application logic with:

```
UPDATE analyzeVeg a set B=(SELECT AVG(p1/(p1+p2)) FROM blocks b where b.city_id = a.city_id) WHERE a.city_id IN(SELECT city_id FROM blocks where block_id IN( :updated_block_ids ))
```

took me 19ms to update